# XNA draw model with depthBuffer, but over other models (like 3dMax Gizmo)

Tags: c#, .net, xna, rendering

As you can understand, i'm trying to create gizmo for level editor, but i ran into an issue.
In order to draw my gizmo over other models, i set

```
 GraphicsDevise.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.None;
```

Because there is no depth test, sometimes I get folowing situation.

[image]

I know that I can resolve this problem with `renderTarget`, but I don't want to mess with Draw.

Can you give me a sugestion how can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to draw in two passes ideally - draw your gizmo after rendering the models etc, then you don't need to worry about depth testing

Comment: Do that, or draw all your regular geometry, then clear your depth/stencil buffer, but don't disable it - then draw the gizmo which will now depth test against itself, but not the rest of the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the @melak47, i resolved the problem

in main Draw call, i draw gizmo the last, and inside gizmo, before drawing geometry i call

```
_GD.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, new Vector4(0), 65535, 0);
```